# How good are inflation expectations as a predictor on inflation?

Tags: forecasting, least-squares, lags, macroeconomics, forecastability

I want to research inflation expectations and how well they predict inflation. I have found some past articles but none of them explain how to forecast inflation using inflation expectations. I have a dataset from 2012 to 2022 on inflation, household inflation expectations, firms inflation expectations, market inflation expectations and then the break-even inflation rate collected from the bond market. I´ve tried using simple OLS to estimate these results, with inflation as the dependent variable and expectations to be the independent variable but none of them are significant (high P-value).

The data is collected quarterly and Inflation expectations are one year ahead (what people and the bond market think will be the inflation in the next 12 months). I know that the data is non-stationary and has serial correlation, I could possibly take first-differences on the dataset and estimate again or use GLS instead.

So basically I have gathered the data I need but I cannot wrap my head around the next step, how often should I lag? What would be the best-fit model?

I was thinking taking the measurement errors, lag inflation expectations by 4 quarters, compare them to actual inflation, use that historical error to forecast future inflation, but I have no Idea how that is done.

Hopefully someone here has an experience in forecasting inflation, sorry about the long post.

Comment: I suspect that "inflation expectations" may be a better "predictor" of current and recent inflation than of future inflation.  You could try different lags (including 0 and negative) and see where any relationship is strongest

Comment: Maybe this is a better fit for https://economics.stackexchange.com/   ?

Comment: From what you have said, you have 44 obs, so 43 differences, for a time period with historically low inflation. Given that there was not much inflation to explain, intuitively it is understandable you would have difficulty finding independent variables with significant coefficients.